# Can't Mount Blank DVD, Only Video DVD and music CD

Tags: mount

I'm hoping someone can help me with this issue. I've tried many suggestions on here but nothing seems to be working. I think it has something to do with my partition. I was uninstalling an OS and accidentally turn of the computer in the process. Ever since I've been having all kind of issues. Right now I am not able to mount blank DVD, just video DVD, and music cd. 
Computer:Dell xps M1530/ Xfce/14.04.2/64 bit/nvidia driver
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a readout from terminal:
$ ▶ udisks --mount /dev/sr0
Mount failed: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
hghershey @ hghershey-dell  ~
└─ $ ▶ ^C
hghershey @ hghershey-dell  ~
└─ $ ▶ sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /cdrom
[sudo] password for hghershey: 
mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Answer (score 1):

due to low points, I cant comment, but I think, mount command is to mount a file-system, which on a blank disk,  doesn't exist. ... I would probably edit out that bit giving up the mac address of computers on your local network.

Youll need to write a File system, to be able to mount it.

Comment: Thanks. That's what happen when you don't know much about mac addresses. I will google "how to write a file system" and see if that works. Thanks again.